# howto route with collection's param in iron router Meteor JS

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

It is common way to route collection News as below using _id params,

```
this.route('newsPage', {
path:'/news/:_id',
data: function(){ return News.findOne(this.params._id);}
});
```

when News collection is declared like this
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990bf7"), "name" : myName, "body": mybody }
I am trying to route like this.

```
this.route('newsPage', {
path:'/news/:name',
data: function(){ return News.findOne(this.params.name);}
});
```

so I can route /news/myName. in MongoDB _id is unique, my News collections name params are unique too. Is it possible to route like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: function(){ return News.findOne({name: this.params.name});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it should be. If the names are unique, I don't see a problem why this would cause any problems.